# normal distribution strange probability

Tags: normal-distribution

Given the particular normal distribution specified below, what is the probability that a random observation falls within the specified range .004 greater and less than the average?

original Lower limit  is .496

original upper limit is .504

$$\mu = .500$$ defective equipment cause the average to change to $$\mu = .449$$

$$\sigma = .002$$

new Lower limit  is .445

new upper limit is .453

So how do you compensate for your average changing because of defective equipment?

---

OLD info
When I use my ti 89 normal cdf function I get 2.24 which isn't even a probability. Is there something special I need to do because my average changes or is there something special about these numbers?

Comment: Are the numbers accurate?  With the mean this small, even your lower limit is effectively impossible. 20 sigma event and all.

Comment: Well, maybe I am misunderstanding your question.  I thought you were asking "given a mean of .449 and a standard deviation of .002 what is the probability that an observation falls between .496 and .504 ?".  As I say, the answer to that is 0 to any sensible precision level.  But maybe I have the wrong question in mind, or maybe there's a typo in the numbers.

Comment: @lulu Yes the numbers are accurate, but I did a poor job of explaining the question after reading out loud to myself several times. I am working on editing it to make more sense. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I see the edit, but the sentence "I have a normal distribution that I am trying to calculate the probability it stays between my upper and lower limit." is still a bit unclear.  do you mean "Given the particular normal distribution specified below, what is the probability that a random observation falls within the specified range?"

Comment: @lulu Yes :). Thank you.

Comment: To be clear:  that question is entirely standard, and your calculator can certainly do it.  But, more to the event, your range is exactly a 2 sigma band around the mean...hence the usual estimate (68,95, 98.7) applies and the answer is approximately .95 , or is this still not the right question?

Comment: @lulu Yes that is correct, but don't have to compensate somehow for the average changing?

Comment: I don't see why the average changing has anything to do with it.  That's why I keep repeating the question, to make sure I am not missing something.  As I understand it you are asking "An observation is drawn from a normal distribution with known mean and known st. dev..  What is the probability that this observation is within 2$\sigma$ of the mean?"  that question has nothing to do with any other distributions that might have come up in the past or in some other context.  It's entirely self-contained.

Comment: @lulu It was confusing to me because statistics is not my strong suit :D.

Comment: No problem; glad if this clarified things.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mu=0.5$ and $\sigma=0.002$, $P(0.496<X<0.504)=P(\frac{0.496-0.5}{0.002}<Z<\frac{0.504-0.5}{0.002})=\Phi(2)-\Phi(-2)\approx 0.9545$, where $Z$ is the standard normal r.v. and $\Phi(\cdot)$ its cumulative density function.

If $\mu=0.499$ and $\sigma=0.002$, $P(0.496<X<0.504)=P(\frac{0.495-0.499}{0.002}<Z<\frac{0.503-0.499}{0.002})=\Phi(2)-\Phi(-2)\approx 0.9545$.